# How to display maximum and minimum value on the basis of date selected in High Charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

I want to display a line on maximum and minimum value in my graph. here is js fiddle example.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/yaxis-plotlines/
```

In this example the maximum and minimum value are hard coded but in my case i'm getting them using this method

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math,arr);
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math,arr);
    console.log(max+"minimum"+min);
```

Where arr is the array of y-axis.

The problem is Suppose i'm displaying graph of last 5 years if i select a date range of last 6 month it still show me the max value of last 5 years not last 6 months because my array is of last 5 years value. if i want to display max value on the basis of i select date in graph how can i acheive this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update min and max when chart redraw. the min and max is calculated based on selected range

```
[Fiddle][1]
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/xq8tezqr/

                var start = this.xAxis[0].min,
                    end = this.xAxis[0].max;
                var arr = data.filter(function(e){
                    return e[0]>=start && e[0]<=end
                }).map(function(e){return e[1]});
                var max = Math.max.apply(Math,arr);
                var min = Math.min.apply(Math,arr);
                console.log(max+"minimum"+min);
```